# Create multiple arrays in one line

Tags: arrays, ruby

I did:

```
a, b = Array.new(2, [0, 0])
a[0] = 1
```

I have:

```
a # => [1, 0]
```

I have a problem with `b`, which is the same as `a`:

```
b # => [1, 0]
```

The problem is reference address.

Help me initialize array in one line.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by writing all your code in one line?

Comment: `a, b = Array.new(2) { [0, 0] }`.

Comment: As a side note, if you are doing this in any sort of large loop, you should manually create two arrays yourself. Otherwise, you end up creating three arrays when you only need two, and the garbage collection on that is expensive, when used in large loops.

Comment: What is the problem with `b` or reference address? State your problem clearly.

Comment: I would write two lines: `a = [0, 0]` and `b = [0, 0]` – much easier to read and no overhead.

Comment: @Stefan it doesn't come soon to new developers that readability is much more (the most?) valuable than few saved lines of code. Been there, done that :)

Comment: @JeroenHeier Because I want to count many conditions, i have to initialize then use +=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mentioned [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-c-new-label-Common+gotchas):

> When sending the second parameter (to `Array.new`), the same object will be used as the value for all the array elements:

So, as @mudasobwa already suggested in the comments, you need to use the block version which uses the result of block for each element:

```
a, b = Array.new(2) { [0, 0] }
 => [[0, 0], [0, 0]]

a[0] = 1

a
 => [1, 0]

b
 => [0, 0]
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it is in general not seen as productive to answer duplicate questions since it fragments the knowledge across the site. Rather, simply vote to close as a duplicate, and move on. This exact same question has been asked and answered literally dozens of times already on [so], it doesn't really require yet another answer saying the exact same thing as a hundred other ones.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh Thanks for your explain, I  really don't read carefully. My bad!

Comment: @JörgWMittag I agree completely that it is not productive to provide answers to questions with already answered duplicates. I myself try to find a duplicate first. Failing to do so, I put my answer there. Same thing happened here. Anyways, duplicate or not, an answer is not downvotable if it is solving the problem correctly. Right?

Comment: If you hover over the downvote arrow, the tooltip gives one example of why you might want to downvote an answer: "This answer is not useful". Different people interpret "useful" differently. Some interpret it as "useful for the asker", some interpret it as "useful for themselves", some interpret it as "making the world a better place", some interpret it as "making [so] a better place". I can see why someone who subscribes to the latter interpretation may find that answering duplicate questions does not make [so] a better place. But you have to ask the downvoter if you want a definite answer.